How to Hide Password in Admin Panel When Creating a New User?
I have encountered an issue in the admin panel of my application. When creating a new user and setting the password, the password is displayed in plain text.
Here is a brief description of the problem:

Navigate to the admin panel.
Select the option to create a new user.
Enter a password for the new user.

Expected behavior:
The password should be hidden and displayed as dots or asterisks (e.g., ********).
Actual behavior:
The password is displayed in plain text, which poses a security risk.

Could someone guide me on how to modify the admin panel so that the password is not displayed in plain text?
That didn't help either
Link
admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

from user import models


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Define the admin pages for users."""
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display = ['id', 'email', 'name']
    search_fields = ['id', 'name', 'email']
    readonly_fields = ['last_login']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.password = make_password(obj.password)
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(models.User, UserAdmin)


Use the PasswordInput widget for the password form field.
For example, here is a snippet of the django.contrib.auth user creation form:
class BaseUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
    password.
    """

    error_messages = {
        "password_mismatch": _("The two password fields didn’t match."),
    }
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"autocomplete": "new-password"}),
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"autocomplete": "new-password"}),
        strip=False,
        help_text=_("Enter the same password as before, for verification."),
    )


I haven't tried this - but maybe you can use the django.contrib.auth stuff in your app directly (be sure to read the django docs). Something like this perhaps:
# forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from user import models


class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User

# admmin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from user import models
from .forms import MyUserCreationForm


@admin.register(models.User)
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    """Define the admin pages for users."""
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display = ['id', 'email', 'name']
    search_fields = ['id', 'name', 'email']
    readonly_fields = ['last_login']
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm


